# How to detect an issue with an unusual Azure slowdown

Tags: azure

I have an MVC based web app running on Azure. The CPU performance of it has been very predictable over the past five months. However, over the past 24 hours, and most recently, from 1:00 pm to 1:30 pm Eastern time, today, in the USA, I have had CPU spikes nearing 100%. The image below, which is for the past 7 days shows this.

[image]

This CPU spike is not coming from my app or my users. There has not been an abnormal increase in users, user activity or queries. I also checked Google Analytics to see if perhaps my site was getting hammered by random users etc. It showed nothing out of the ordinary.

There also was a corresponding huge jump in data going out of my site, which is highly unusual. The second image shows data egress for the past week. However, as I said, I checked my Azure SQL Database Query Store and it shows absolutely nothing out of the ordinary. Furthermore, my DTU percentage never even neared 100% during this time, which it certainly would have if this much data was pulled from the database.

[image]

I have basically ruled out anything amiss on my end. Is there some way I can check to see if there were issues with Azure causing this?

Comment: There are two ways that you can check to see if something in the Azure platform itself was causing this issue: 1: Check https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/. This will tell you if there is currently any active incidents in a region for a given service. You can also click the Status History link on this page to see if something happened in the past that has been resolved. I checked during the time period you mentioned, and nothing was listed. 2: Open a support ticket with Azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are suspecting an underlying Azure platform issue, both Azure Service Health and Azure Resource Health are useful resources to determine if you are being impacted by platform issue.

Azure Service Health provides personalized service health information when Azure platform issues impact your resources.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/service-health-overview

Azure Resource Health provides visibility into whether your Azure resources are healthy or unhealthy.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/resource-health-overview

For a list of supported Azure resources, you can refer to this article which also describes the set of health checks being performed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-health/resource-health-checks-resource-types